# Adjusted mean with emmeans at 3 expressions

Tags: r, expression, linear-regression, mean, emmeans

I know how to get the adjusted mean by emmeans when I have 2 expressions present, such as with sex.
sex == 1 : men, sex == 2 : women --> 2 expressions.
The associated model with the subsequent adjusted mean (EMM) calculation is:

```
mean_MF <- lm(LZ~age + SES_3 + sex, data = MF)
summary(mean_MF)
emmeans(mean_MF, ~ sex)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
> emmeans(mean_MF, ~ sex)
 sex emmean     SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
   1   7.05 0.0193 20894     7.02     7.09
   2   6.96 0.0187 20894     6.93     7.00
```

Results are averaged over the levels of: belastet_SZ, belastet_SNZ, guteSeiten_SZ, guteSeiten_SNZ, SES_3
Confidence level used: 0.95
But if I want to calculate the adjusted mean of a variable with 3 values, I only get an adjusted mean of a common value? expression, instead of for all 3.
e.g. for age (Alter), here I have 3 characteristics which are coded as follows:

> 18-30 years: 1
> 31-40 years: 2
> 41-51 years: 3

What else do I need to add to the emmeans function so that I get the adjusted means of all three variables?

```
F_Alter <- lm(LZ~ SES_3 + Alter, data = Frauen)
summary(F_Alter)
emmeans(F_Alter, ~ Alter)
```

The summary of (F_Alter) looks as follows:

```
> summary(F_Alter)

Call:
lm(formula = LZ ~ SES_3 + Alterfactor, data = Frauen)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.2303 -1.1162  0.1951  1.1220  3.8838 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7.44956    0.05653 131.777  < 2e-16 ***
SES_3mittel  -0.42539    0.04076 -10.437  < 2e-16 ***
SES_3niedrig -1.11411    0.05115 -21.781  < 2e-16 ***
Alterfactor  -0.07309    0.02080  -3.513 0.000444 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.889 on 14481 degrees of freedom
  (5769 Beobachtungen als fehlend gelöscht)
Multiple R-squared:  0.03287,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03267 
F-statistic:   164 on 3 and 14481 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

In the following output I only get a value of 1.93 instead of my 3 expressions and the respective specific EEM's.

```
emmeans(F_Alter, ~ Alter)
 Alter emmean     SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
  1.93    6.8 0.0179 14481     6.76     6.83

Results are averaged over the levels of: SES_3 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

What can I change in the emmeans formula to get the output for my 3 age expressions (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: Your code should work, is `Alter` coded as a factor or a numeric?  It will need to be a factor for the model to be estimated correctly and for the means to be calculated for each group.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva it was not coded as a factor. I have done that now, but unfortunately I still get only one common value. 

`MF$Alterfactor <- as.factor(MF$Alterfactor)
F_Alter <- lm(LZ~ SES_3 + Alterfactor, data = Frauen)
summary(F_Alter)
emmeans(F_Alter, ~ Alterfactor)`

`> emmeans(F_Alter, ~ Alterfactor)
 Alterfactor emmean     SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
        1.93    6.8 0.0179 14481     6.76     6.83

Results are averaged over the levels of: SES_3 
Confidence level used: 0.95`

Where is the error in my formula?

Comment: there is no error in the formula.  Can you put the results of the model summary from `summary(F_Alter)` into the question text?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva for sure! I have added the Summary(F_Alter) to the question text. Thanks already!

Comment: From your model summary it is clear that `Alterfactor` is not coded as a factor.  In the comment above you changed `MF$Alterfactor` to be a factor, but your model used the `Frauen` dataset and not the `MF` dataset!  If you set `Alterfactor` to be a factor in the dataset you use to estimate the model it will work as you expect.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Great, now it worked! Thank you from the bottom of my heart for your help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The predictor `Alter` in the original question was not coded as a factor, and so it was being treated as a continuous numeric variable in the model estimation and by `emmeans`.

The problem is fixed by creating a new factor variable,

```
Frauen$Alterfactor = as.factor(Frauer$Alter)
```

and then using this new variable as the predictor in the model.